# How to import rospy and cv2 at the same python3 script?

Tags: ros

### Problem

Can not import cv2 in python3 env like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so: undefined symbol: PyCObject_Type
```

### Solution

The first way is to use .bashrc like:

```
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
export PATH="$PATH:/path/anaconda2/bin"
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/:
export PYTHONPATH="/home/users/anaconda2/envs/env_name/lib/python3.5/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH"
```

To test,

```
conda activate env_name # the python3 environment name
python -c "import rospy"
python -c "import cv2"
```

It will work without any error output!!!

But it will not work when you ssh to the robot contorller, for example:`intera.sh sim`

Answer (score 0):

The second success way is editing the header file like:

```
import sys
sys.path.remove('/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages')
import cv2
# make sure to use import rospy in the future
sys.path.append('/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages')
```